# Run scheduled task on wireless connection

Tags: windows, wifi, scheduled-task, windows-event-log, login-script

I'm trying to set up a completely wireless office, with mostly Windows 7 and a few Windows 8 clients, and one problem I've run into is login scripts. The security guys don't want to allow machine authentication, only user, so connecting to wireless before logon is not possible for me. I've found articles that mention how to do this via scheduled tasks, triggered on Event ID 8003 in WLAN-AutoConfig. However, this seems to fire on association, before IP assignment, so the call to the login script (on the domain controller) fails. If I tell it to delay 10 seconds after the event, it usually works, but sometimes fails as it still hasn't finished the DHCP process, and I need a reliable solution that allows the users to get to work as soon as possible after logon. I've found an Event 4002 in NetworkProfiles that seems to fire after IP assignment, but it also seems to fire at other times as well, and I don't want the script to run while the user is in the middle of something.

Does anyone know of an event that is only fired once on wireless connection after the IP address has been received? Or is there a better way of doing this?

If you require more info, please let me know.

Comment: What kind of scheduled task is it? Which operating system? If it's >= Windows 8 and Powershell then I'd just poll for an existing IP address with [`Get-NetIPAddress`](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/10/powertip-use-powershell-to-get-ip-addresses.aspx), check to see if there's an IP address with known values (subnet perhaps) and then continue on from there, or give up after say, 30 seconds

Comment: Awful idea, the completely wireless office, and this is this only the start of your problems if you continue down this path.

Comment: @MarkHenderson, sorry, should have specified, clients are mostly Win 7, some Win 8 (will edit question with this info). A backup idea I have is to run a script at association that checks for connectivity before executing the logon script. But that's not a very nice solution.

Comment: @HopelessN00b, this wasn't my idea. :-S I already know a few other problems that this is going to cause us (password expiry, locked out accounts, GPOs not processing right away, etc), but I just have to make it work the best I can.